# Data html com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

estou com uma duvida.

Vou fazer com que o jquery fique encarregado de inserir as imagens dependendo da largura, sendo que cada imagem vai estar no data-mobile e data-desktop.

```
<img class="data-img" src="" data-mobile="url" data-desktop="url" />


$(document).ready(function() {
    var device = $(window).innerWidth() > 515 ? "desktop" : "mobile";
    $("img.data-img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data(device));
    });
});
```

A minha duvida é a seguinte:

Seu eu tiver varios **img** um vai substituir o outro ou a função será chamada para cada um?

Comment: Como você está utiliznado o `.each()` ele vai percorrer cada imagem com a classe que você especificou e aplicar a imagem corretamente, porém acredito que há outras maneiras melhores de se fazer isso.

Comment: Quais seriam @BrunoRomualdo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `.each` será chamada pra cada `<img>` com a classe especificada e alterar o `src` de acordo com o `data-` de cada elemento percorrido.

No exemplo abaixo, a bola de basquete seria "mobile" e a de tênis "desktop". Altere o tamanho da janela e veja que cada imagem irá mudar quando a tela for menor do que `515px` e maior:

```js
//$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).on("load resize", function(){
            var device = $(window).innerWidth() > 515 ? "desktop" : "mobile";
            $("img.data-img").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).data(device));
            });
 });
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img height="100" class="data-img" src="" data-mobile="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Basketball.jpeg/220px-Basketball.jpeg" data-desktop="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41IJsgFvWzL._SX355_.jpg" />
<img height="100" class="data-img" src="" data-mobile="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41IJsgFvWzL._SX355_.jpg" data-desktop="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Basketball.jpeg/220px-Basketball.jpeg" />
<img height="100" class="data-img" src="" data-mobile="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Basketball.jpeg/220px-Basketball.jpeg" data-desktop="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41IJsgFvWzL._SX355_.jpg" />
```

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez @DvD

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @DvD já responde a sua pergunta. Porém como esse é um assunto bastante amplo e discutido (inclusive eu me interesso muito em uma solução padrão) vou deixar uma alternativa que espero em breve ser adaptada para todos os browsers.

## A tag `<picture>` do html5

Essa nova tag nos permite tratar imagens da mesma forma como tratamos a tag `<audio>`, onde podemos colocar vários formatos para funcionar em diferentes tipos de browsers.
Nela, podemos usar o atributo `media` com a mesma sintaxe de quando usamos os `@media-queries` no CSS, para mostrar uma imagem referente ao tamanho da tela.

Veja este exemplo (redimensione a tela) também tem no [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/at6droo0/1/):

```css
picture, img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset="https://vidanimal.com.br/wp-content/uploads/papillon.jpg" media="(max-width: 700px)" alt="Pequeno">
    <source srcset="https://www.blupet.com.br/uploads/pets/26984/2698418092017185025000000.jpg" media="(max-width: 1024px)" alt="Medio">
    <img srcset="https://www.ultracurioso.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sao-bernardo.jpg" alt="Grande (imagem fallback padrão)">
</picture>
```

Ao redimensionar a tela será mostrado a imagem correspondente ao `@media-querie` que você definiu no atributo `media`, nele você pode usar os atributos `max-width`, `min-width`, `max-height`, `min-height`, `orientation` entre outros que estejam de acordo com a sintaxe dos `@media-queries`.

Nos teste que fiz funcionou no Chrome(v61), FireFox(v55) e Opera(v48), no IE11 tive que adicionar mais uma linha na tag `<img>` padrão com um `src` para poder funcionar, ficou assim:

```
<img src="https://www.ultracurioso.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sao-bernardo.jpg" srcset="https://www.ultracurioso.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sao-bernardo.jpg" alt="Grande (imagem fallback padrão)">
```

Assim funcionou nos outros navegadores que citei sem dar conflito.

Pode ver o suporte a essa tag no [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture) e utilizá-la caso veja que vem a acalhar, e ainda caso não esteja seguro há um plugins JS chamado [Picturefill](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) que promete ser bem `crossbrowser` e utiliza  a mesma sintaxe que mostrei.

A resposta ficou meio grande, mas se alguém tiver uma sugestão de edição basta comentar.

Fontes: [Webdesign.tutsplus](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015), Google ;) e [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/picturefill-2-0-responsive-images-and-the-perfect-polyfill/).

Comment: Nossa, muito top. Pelo fato de eu ter pedido jquery nao vou marcar como resposta para a duvida. Mas a sua resposta é muito top, vou mudar o que estava fazendo para este picture. Obrigado @BrunoRomualdo